# Display / hide a UITableView header (UITextField) in the same way as the Mail app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to display and hide a UITableView header (a UITextField) in the exact same way as the standard Mail app does with it's UISearchBar, but have not been able to figure out how to implement the behavior.

The behavior that is relevant to me is as follows:

- On first display, the header (search bar) is hidden.
- When the user scrolls down, the header is revealed.
- Even when the table content (rows) do not fill up the whole table view, the header can be scrolled back out of sight (very important).
- On returning to the same view, the position of the header is exactly where it was left (either fully in view, fully out of view, or somewhere in between).

The key is being able to scroll the header back out of sight even when the table content (rows) do not fill up the whole view.

I have tried setting contentOffset, and while I can hide the header for the first view by doing so, the header cannot be scrolled back out of sight when the table content (rows) do not fill up the whole table view with just this method.

Can anybody offer any advice here?

Comment: How are you assigning the search bar as the header? I'm able to get the desired effect with [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar]; then using the contentOffset property as you've described in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get what you were looking for? I have this in some code from a while back that does what you are asking. Shows search bar in header when pulled down 40px. Hides back up under navigation bar when table scrolled up 40px.

searching is an iVar flag I set when the search bar is active.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    CGFloat amountOfDrag = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    UIEdgeInsets edgeAtEntry = self.tableView.contentInset;
    UIEdgeInsets edgeSetNew;
    CGFloat underlay = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
    CGFloat searchBarViewHeight = 44.0f;
    BOOL needsReset = NO;
    if (amountOfDrag <= -40 && edgeAtEntry.top == underlay - searchBarViewHeight) {
        needsReset = YES;
        edgeSetNew = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f + underlay, 0.0f, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0.0f);
    } else if (amountOfDrag >= 40 && edgeAtEntry.top != underlay - searchBarViewHeight) {
        needsReset = YES;
        edgeSetNew = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-searchBarViewHeight + underlay, 0.0f, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0.0f); //hides searchbar under navbar
    }

    if (needsReset && !searching) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        scrollView.contentInset = edgeSetNew;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```